# If checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I want to be able to change the `var chars` according to the checkboxes checked.

Right now, I was looking around for some if checkbox is checked stuff, but when ever I attempt it, the password comes up blank.

**JS code**

```
function randomString() {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz=-][';/.,`~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{:?><";
    var string_length = 10;
    var randomstring = '';

    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }

    if($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')){
        var lowstring = randomstring.toLowerCase();
        document.randform.randomfield.value = lowstring;
    } else {
        document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;
    }

    //  document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring; //
}
```

**Html code**

```
<div class="preference">
    <div class="form2">
        <div class="wanted"> <!-- Toggle Special Characters -->
            <label class="input-toggle">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" checked>
                <span></span>
            </label>
            <p>Toggle Special Characters</p>
            <div class="wanted"> <!-- Toggle Numbers -->
                <label class="input-toggle">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked>
                    <span></span>
                </label>
                <p>Toggle Numbers</p>
                <div class="wanted"> <!-- Toggle Uppercase -->
                    <label class="input-toggle">
                        <input type="checkbox" checked>
                        <span></span>
                    </label>
                    <p>Toggle Uppercase</p>
                    <div class="wanted"> <!-- Toggle Lowercase -->
                        <label class="input-toggle">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked>
                            <span></span>
                        </label>
                        <p>Toggle Lowercase</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#checkbox1').is(':checked')`  is correct while ID are unique. What's the problem?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude If then isn't working with it.

Comment: You have another problem, not that. `$('#checkbox1').is(':checked')` returns true or false according with the state, test it in the console. Your problem seems to be other, but this question is not clear to see what happens in your code. Create a working example (jsfiddle.net, stacksnippets, etc) reproducing the issue and share here. Otherwise this should be closed as offtopic (read the help center for more info)